# (C Programming) How do I insert string into a character array and then print out all the elements of this array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

I have this string that is presented in the form of character array `temp`. And I want to insert this character array to another array `temp_list` and then print out the contents of this array. In other words, storing many character arrays in a single array. Can anyone tell me if this is possible and how can I make it work?

This is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
int main()
{
    char temp[5] = "begin";
    char temp_list [10];
    temp_list[0] = temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(temp_list); i++)
    {
        printf("Labels: %s,", temp_list[i]);
    }
}
```

When I run this program, it prints out gibberish.

Any form of guidance would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:

Thank you for the answers. They are all really helpful. But I have another question... what if I have multiple character arrays that I want to insert to `temp_list`? Using `strcpy` multiple times seem to not work, since I am assuming the function basically replaces the entire content of the `temp_list` with the string passed with `strcpy`?

Comment: You need to make room for the null character.

Comment: You should enable all warnings and listen to them. `temp_list[0] = temp;` This is not how a string is copied.

Comment: Does that code compile? You have an assignment from `char*` to `char` which shouldn’t be ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a bunch of misconceptions regarding strings. Your array `temp` needs to be big enough to also store the null-terminator, so it needs a size of at least `6` in this case:

```
char temp[6] = "begin"; // 5 chars plus the null terminator
```

To copy the string, use `strcpy`:

```
char temp_list[10];
strcpy(temp_list, temp);
```

To print it, pass `temp_list`, not `temp_list[i]`, also you don't need that loop:

```
printf("%s\n", temp_list);
```

The final program could look like this:

```
int main()
{
    char temp[6] = "begin";
    char temp_list[10];
    strcpy(temp_list, temp);
    printf("%s\n", temp_list);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if I would like to insert more than one character array? I guess, `strcpy` would no longer be an option, right? Since the function replaces the entire array with one string?

Comment: Depends on how you want to insert more. `strcpy` copies the string, but doesn't change anything after the null-terminator. You can also use `memcpy` to copy a fixed amount of bytes, and `strcat` lets you concatenate strings. For instance if after `strcpy(temp_list, temp);` you would call `strcat(temp_list, "Hi!");` it would print `beginHi!`

Comment: I was thinking to make it like {"hello", "world"} sort of array. Is that not possible in C?

Comment: You can try: `char temp[][10] =  {"hello", "world"}; char temp_list[20]; strcpy(temp_list, temp[0]); strcat(temp_list, temp[1]);`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Sorry, but I have another question. It printed out "helloworld." Do you think it is possible to make it into a formal array so I can access each word later? In order to access it like: temp_list[0] or temp_list[1]. I could just concatenate a divider after each word to separate it, but I am wondering if there are other alternatives in C?

Comment: @Tina In this case you probably want `temp_list` to be a 2D array, too, like this: `char temp_list[2][20]; strcpy(temp_list[0], temp[0]); strcpy(temp_list[1], temp[1]); printf("%s %s\n", temp_list[0], temp_list[1]);`

Comment: I figured. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You have three problems here.  First, `temp` is not big enough to hold the string "begin".  Strings in C are null terminated, so this string actually takes up 6 bytes, not 5.  So make `temp` big enough to hold this string:

```
char temp[6] = "begin";
```

Or better yet:

```
char temp[] = "begin";
```

Which sizes the array exactly as needed for the string.  The second problem is here:

```
temp_list[0] = temp;
```

You're assigning an array (actually a pointer to the array's first element) to the first element of another array.  That's a type mismatch of assigning a `char *` to a `char`.  Even if the types matched, that's not how strings are copied.  For that, use the `strcpy` function:

```
strcpy(temp_list, temp);
```

Finally, you're not printing the result correctly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(temp_list); i++)
{
    printf("Labels: %s,", temp_list[i]);
}
```

The `%s` format specifier expects a pointer to a `char` array in order to print a string, but you're passing in a single characters.  Mismatching format specifiers invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

For printing single characters, use `%c` instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(temp_list); i++)
{
    printf("Labels: %c,", temp_list[i]);
}
```

Or you can get rid of the loop and just print the whole string using `%s`:

```
printf("Labels: %s", temp_list);
```

Comment: One more thing: he is using incorrect format specifier to print char in printf.

Comment: @machine_1 Good catch.  Updated.